# allow usesCleartextTraffic if required Android Studio

Tags: android, android-webview, android-manifest

i have 2 phones, api(28, 17) so when request HTTP, it work with api 17

but not in api 28, friend said that, i must use

```
 android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

in Manifest, but when build it work in the phone (api 28), api 17 not get request.

so is there any if condition, i can check sdk version,
i tried, this.in java Main activity

```
   if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 23) {
         android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    }
```

any help to make this app get request from http without any error for both devices.

but i don't know much, im still beginner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AndroidManifest:

```
<application
            android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

and in res>xml  add `network_security_config.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"/>
</network-security-config>
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in Android Developers Blogspot, you don’t have to set minSdkVersion or targetSdkVersion of your app to 23 (Android Marshmallow) to use android:usesCleartextTraffic. On older platforms, this attribute is simply ignored and thus has no effect.[Check this out](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/04/protecting-against-unintentional.html)

Hope this solves your query.

Comment: i already read this in another thread, but i still not figure out yet.!

Answer (score 1):

Use [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley). It's an easy to use API for Network-Traffic. Also it takes all the stuff for you in the handshaking and so on. But basic knowledge for Network is still required.